# find closest future date and time from today's from in json response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am getting a response from my api where `start_time` is given. I want to extract the id from json whose next date time is closest to current date time which does not include dates from past.

An example of my json response:

```
[
    {
        "expected": {
            "id": 1,
            "start_time": "2021-10-01T06:35:00.659Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "expected": {
            "id": 2,
            "start_time": "2021-11-30T17:08:29.307Z"
        }
    },
    {   
        "expected": {
            "id": 3,
            "start_time": "2021-11-30T09:49:18.574Z"
        }
    },
    {   
        "expected": {
            "id": 4,
            "start_time": "2021-09-30T15:08:29.303Z"
        }
    },
]
```

Here what I have done untill now is to find the closest date time from today's date time:

```
const today = new Date().getTime();
const result = response.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
    const diffA =
        new Date(a.expected.shift_start_time).getTime() - today;
    const diffB =
        new Date(b.expected.shift_start_time).getTime() - today;
    return diffA - diffB;
})[0];
```

using this I am getting the `id` of closest date time from today. But the `result` sometimes also include a `start_time` from past date if that is closest to todays date.

I want to get `id` which does not include `start_time` from past dates. I am unable to get the logic how it can be done

Another approach which I did:

```
var today = moment();
for (let index = 0; index < response.length; index++) {
    const element = response[index].start_time;
    var dateDiff = today.diff(element, 'days') * -1;
    if (dateDiff >= 0) {
        console.log('>>d>>', dateDiff);
    }
}
```

console:

```
>>d>> -0
>>d>> 1
>>d>> -0
```

From here how can I return the required response?? please help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe don't sort the list at all. Since you only need one dateTime which is closest with current Date, sorting the entire 'list' doesn't appear to be the optimal way to have your answer.You can use the following approach,

- Save current DateTimeStamp to a local var
- Start a loop through your list
- Perform a check for your current item if the date is greater than local timeStamp you stored.
- For first element, store the element as your current answer and for every other element compare the diff with the saved timeStamp and modify your answer accordingly.

Comment: `var today = moment();
for (let index = 0; index < response.length; index++) {
 const element = response[index].start_time;
 var dateDiff = today.diff(element, 'days') * -1;
 if (dateDiff >= 0) {
  console.log('>>d>>', dateDiff);
 }
}` so here I am getting `>>d>> -0  >>d>> 1  >>d>> -0`, how will return the required response from here..please help